# Jet of gas striking a disc, what fraction of the total volume is in contact with the disc

Tags: fluid-dynamics, diffusion

In a catalysis experiment, I have a jet of gas coming through a nozzle of cross-sectional area A_1 at a volumetric flow rate F. This strikes a circular disc of area A_2 coated with catalyst, at right angle, and A_1> A_2. How do I find out the amount of gas molecules in contact with the catalyst as a fraction of the total amount of gas I have?

Here, nozzle diameter = 28mm, catalyst diameter= 20mm so they are comparable in magnitude.

Comment: If the nozzle is very near the plate it will be just A2:A1

Comment: What if there is a finite and non-negligible separation? Do we expect some soft of gas-disc to be formed?

Comment: I think you can easily find out how A1 expands after leaving the nozzle, otherwise use se 1/r^2 approach.

Comment: In this case A_1 should be fixed and we expect a parallel jet of gas.

Comment: Then I do not understand your question  what should " some soft of gas-disc " be? and does the reaction not depend on the time of contact?

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a full answer. But you have a layer of gas next to the plate. If the gas was motionless, gas near the plate would diffuse to the surface and be absorbed. The rate of absorption depends on the diffusion rate and probability of absorption.

For a motionless gas, the concentration would drop near the surface because atoms near the surface would be removed from the gas. A moving gas changes this.

With a moving gas, there is a boundary layer against the surface that does not move. Diffusion in that layer controls the rate of absorption. The concentration at the top of that layer does not change. So you need to know the thickness of that layer. Here is a video that goes through it while talking about drag. [DRAG ON FLAT PLATE](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NkJNvD9o3CY)

Comment: Thanks! But in this case the jet of air striked the catalyst plate at right angle, ie velocity parallel to surface normal

Comment: Air flowing just above the boundary layer will flow parallel to the surface. The only role of this layer in your problem is to replenish the gas at the top of the boundary layer.